# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument "UserRepository" at index [0]

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to develop a login flow using passport, but I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument "UserRepository" at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
- If "UserRepository" is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If "UserRepository" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing "UserRepository" */ ]
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { User } from './user/user.entity';
import { UserController } from './user/user.controller';
import { UserService } from './user/user.service';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './auth/local.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    PassportModule,

    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'gokitchen',
      entities: [User, Country],
      synchronize: false,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, UserController],
  providers: [AppService, UserService, LocalStrategy],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async createUser(userData: Partial<User>): Promise<User> {
    const user = this.userRepository.create(userData);
    return await this.userRepository.save(user);
  }

  findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.userRepository.find();
  }

  findOne(email: string): Promise<User | null> {
    return this.userRepository.findOneBy({ email });
  }

  async remove(id: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.userRepository.delete(id);
  }
}
```

**user.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UserService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `UserController` in the `UserModule` there's no need to add it again in the `AppModule`. Meaning you can remove both the `UserController` and the `UserService` from the `AppModule`'s metadata arrays.

If you end up needing access to the `UserService` in another module, you should add the `UserService` to the `exports` of the `UserModule` and then add the `UserModule` to the `imports` of the module that needs the access.